# Is there a way to get my Tkinter GUI to run simultaneously with my code?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am unable to get my GUI and code to run and update together

I had made a D&D combat sim game. I had written it originally as text based, but then, introduced Tkinter to create a GUI and visuals. Within this I created a dialogue/text box. However when I added text to my combat section, I noticed that when my GUI would open, my script would not run until the window was closed. when I switched it, the window would only open when the combat ended.

Disclaimer: GUI is not completely represented here to save space

```py
Blank = tk.Tk()
Canvas = tk.Canvas(Blank, height=720, width=1280)
Canvas.pack()
Frame = tk.Frame(Canvas, bg='#D0B36F')
Frame.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)                 
Textbox = tk.Frame(Frame, bg='white')
Textbox.place(relx=0.3, rely=0.6, relwidth=0.4, relheight=0.25)
Log = tk.Text(Textbox)
Log.pack()
Blank.mainloop()
Combat()
```

I have not received any errors.

Comment: Try using thread to run your `Combat()`: `threading.Thread(target=Combat).start()` before `Blank.mainloop()`.  Of course you need to `import threading`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I know basically nothing about threading, so I couldn't have figured this out by my self

Comment: For a D&D style game `threading` is probably overkill. You can get all the functionality you need with functions and `after()` statements. That said we cannot help much as you have not presented an example of a problem. Your code there is a simple GUI that does not have any errors.